# Adding my Self-Signed Certificate to the Trusted CAS List programatically

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, ca

For my project, I need to add a self-assigned certificate to the trusted CA list so that browsers treat my server as secure connection. I have already produced the certificate using OpenSSL. Now, I need to add to the CA list. I tried to add the certificate manually by this command found from another question

```
sudo cp my.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

But both Mozilla and Chrome still showing the connection as insecure. I will be grateful if anyone can guide me on how I can do this programmatically in JAVA/python/C/C++ or any other language.

[screenshot from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cgdh.png)

Comment: Programmatically trusting self-signed certificates (or any certificate for that matter) is a huge security risk. Don't do this! If you have your project hosted with a domain name,  [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is literally free and trusted by most vendors. Use this instead.

Comment: Hi, I am doing this for internet security course. I know that its very risky but that was my end goal. Anyway thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate